# How can I write more "pythonic" when coding like the following?

Tags: python

```
res = sum((i+j)%k == 0 for x, i in enumerate(a) for j in a[x+1:])
```

where a is an array.

I cannot understand what this code is doing..is the `i in enumerate(a) for j in a[x+1:]` basically a for loop inside that line to save space?

Also how can I write code like this? I am trying to learn python.

Answer (score 5):

This is a generator expression inside a call to the `sum` function.  `sum` just adds things up, so let's look at the generator expression:

```
(i+j)%k == 0 for x, i in enumerate(a) for j in a[x+1:]
```

The `(i+j)%k == 0` part is a boolean expression.  It's either true if `i+j` has a remainder of `0` when dived by `k` or false otherwise.  As a neat little trick, the `True` value has a numeric value of `1` in python, and `False` has a numeric value of `0`.  So this is basically just counting.

```
for x, i in enumerate(a) for j in a[x+1:]
```

This is essentially a nested for loop.

```
for x, i in enumerate(a):
    for j in a[x+1:]:
```

`enumerate` is a function that yields items from an iterable paired with their index, so `[a, b, c]` becomes `[(0, a), (1, b), (2, c)]`

Stick it all together, and this code calculates the number of pairs of elements in a list such that their sum is divisible by`k`

Answer (score 3):

you can "unwind" the code as follows:

```
counter=0   # emulates `sum`
for x, i in enumerate(a):
    for j in a[x+1:]:
       counter += (i+j)%k == 0
```

so it counts the occurrences of `(i+j)` being divisible by `k`, avoiding to count the same half and identical elements (only counts the upper matrix triangle)

List/generator comprehensions are better/faster and more concise when you're creating a list out of another iterable or iterable of iterable, like here: you created a list of booleans (0 or 1) that you `sum` to count the occurrences of `True`.

But don't abuse of them: [proper use of list comprehensions - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695488/proper-use-of-list-comprehensions-python)

sometimes a plain loop to call n times a function is better (also when a side-effect is required).

When used unwisely they can become a nightmare to understand (specially the one-liners with side-effects in them)

Comment: But isn't this technically a generator expression and not a list comprehension? So you never really create a `list` in memory.

Comment: yes, it is a generator comprehension. `sum` doesn't need to have the list in memory so no temp list will be created.

Comment: So the sum function is adding up the counters in this case?

Comment: @jessibird the sum *acts as* the counter. It counts the occurences for when `(i+j)%k == 0`

Answer (score 1):

These are called comprehensions. `enumerate` iterates through an iterable object and returns a tuple `(a, b)` where `a` is the index in the iterable, and `b` is object at that index.

This is a nice piece of pythonic code. As for learning how to understand/write stuff like this, practice, and reading python documentation would be a great place to start. Remember, this is simply just syntactic sugar, you can do the same thing in multiple lines and it will work almost exactly the same.